# Pulling information from a Bid and Ask column in a stock exchange website

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have a trouble of pulling prices on the Bid and Ask columns of this website: [https://banggia.vps.com.vn/chung-khoan/derivative-VN30][1]. Now I can only pull the name of the class, which is "price-table-content". How can I improve these codes so that I can pull prices on the Bid and Ask columns? Any helps to pull these prices are greatly appreciated :)

```
from selenium import webdriver


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.headless = True
path = 'C:/Users/quank/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path, options=options)
url = 'https://banggia.vps.com.vn/chung-khoan/derivative-VN30'
driver.get(url=url)
element = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#root > div > div.content.undefined > 
                                                div.derivative > table.price-table > tbody')
for i in element:
     print(i.get_attribute('outerHTML'))
```

Here is the result of running these codes

```
C:\Users\quank\PycharmProjects\Botthudulieu\venv\Scripts\python.exe 
C:/Users/quank/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/Botthudulieu.py
<tbody class="price-table-content"></tbody>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you check the [network activity](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/) you'll see that the data is retrieved from an api. So query the api directly rather than trying to scrape the site.

```
import requests

data = requests.get('https://bgapidatafeed.vps.com.vn/getpsalldatalsnapshot/VN30F2109,VN30F2110,VN30F2112,VN30F2203').json()
```

Or with `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json('https://bgapidatafeed.vps.com.vn/getpsalldatalsnapshot/VN30F2109,VN30F2110,VN30F2112,VN30F2203')
```

Resulting dataframe:

|  | id | sym | mc | c | f | r | lastPrice | lastVolume | lot | avePrice | highPrice | lowPrice | fBVol | fBValue | fSVolume | fSValue | g1 | g2 | g3 | g4 | g5 | g6 | g7 | mkStatus | listing_status | matureDate | closePrice | ptVol | oi | oichange | lv |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2100 | VN30F2109 | 4 | 1505.1 | 1308.3 | 1406.7 | 1420 | 6018 | 351832 | 1406.49 | 1422.9 | 1390 | 2011 | 0 | 2225.0 | 0 | 1420.00 | 37 | i | 1419.90 | 232 | i | 1419.80 | 3 | i | 1420.10 | 289 | i | 1420.20 | 2 | i | 3 | 356133 | e | A | 0 | 37433 | 3 |
| 1 | 2100 | VN30F2110 | 4 | 1504.3 | 1307.5 | 1405.9 | 1418 | 14 | 462 | 1406.94 | 1422 | 1390 | 0 | 0 | 1.0 | 0 | 1418.00 | 1 | i | 1417.80 | 1 | i | 1417.50 | 1 | i | 1420.00 | 4 | i | 1421.00 | 1 | i | 1 | 523 | e | A | 0 | 193 | 2 |
| 2 | 2100 | VN30F2112 | 4 | 1505.5 | 1308.7 | 1407.1 | 1420 | 1 | 54 | 1424.31 | 1420 | 1390.8 | 0 | 0 |  | 0 | 1412.30 | 1 | i | 1411.60 | 1 | i | 1411.20 | 1 | i | 1420.80 | 1 | i | 1421.20 | 1 | i | 1 | 88 | e | A | 0 | 596 | 1 |
| 3 | 2100 | VN30F2203 | 4 | 1503.9 | 1307.3 | 1405.6 | 1420 | 1 | 50 | 1402.19 | 1420 | 1390 | 0 | 0 |  | 0 | 1412.10 | 1 | i | 1412.00 | 1 | i | 1410.10 | 1 | i | 1420.50 | 1 | i | 1421.00 | 2 | i | 2 | 85 | e | A | 0 | 138 | 1 |

Comment: Thank you so much! I’ve also learned new thing too.